# Hugo: List tags with link and comma separated?

Tags: hugo

I'm using Hugo to make a website, and I want to show a clickable comma separated list of all the tags of a page.

I can simply show all tags like this:

```
Tags: {{ delimit .Params.tags ", " }}
```

However, then the tags aren't clickable. I can make them clickable by using `range`:

```
Tags:
{{ range .Params.tags }}
<a href='{{ "/tags/" | relLangURL }}{{ . | urlize }}'>{{ . | humanize }}</a>,
{{ end }}
```

But then I have a trailing comma that's not supposed to be there.

I had this fix where I wrap the comma in a css class `unlessLast` and then hide it using css:

```
.unlessLast:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a nice way of not even generating the trailing comma with Hugo.

So, how do I remove this comma properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured something out, where instead of a trailing `,` I add one in front of each element, but hide the first one. Checking if an element is the first one is easy:

```
{{ range $i, $e := .Params.tags -}}
    {{- if $i -}}, {{ end -}}
    <a href='{{ "/tags/" | relLangURL }}{{ . | urlize }}'>{{ $e | humanize }}</a>
{{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this statement on li layout, this will show as a separate list with a link

```
{{ range $key, $value := .Params.categories }}
  {{if ne $value "null"}}
    <span class="tag-style-1"><a href="/tag/{{ $value | urlize  }}">{{ $value }}</a></span>
  {{end}}
{{ end }}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have this workaround:

```
<strong>{{ Tags: }}</strong>
{{ range $key, $value := .Params.tags }}
   <a href="{{ "/tags/" }}{{ $value | urlize }}">{{ $value }}</a>{{ if ne $key (sub (len $.Params.tags) 1) }}, {{ else }}{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

Code explanation:
The comma for the last element will be skipped, this is, asking if the loop haven't reached the last element *{{ if ne $key (sub (len $.Params.tags) 1) }}*, until not, the comma will be printed. Note that here we're using the global operator $ to reach the global context for .Params.tags and avoid the context of the range loop <- **This is important**.

A more short approach could be this:

```
<strong>{{ Tags: }}</strong>
{{ range $key, $value := .Params.tags }}
   <a href="{{ "/tags/" }}{{ $value | urlize }}">{{ if $key }}, {{ end }}{{ $value }}</a>
{{ end }}
```

Code explanation:
Hugo will be treat 0 as false, then, it will not print the comma for the first element and will be printed for the rest, behind the tag (ej: tag1 ,tag2 ,tag3). The problem of this approach is that the comma will be urlized too.